# What does mean "математик в законе"?

Tags: значения

I encountered a description of a person as "математик в законе". Does it mean he is a criminal?

Comment: Will you provide some context, or can you quote the sentence or the paragraph, where you encountered that? The phrase can mean he is a criminal, or authoritative, or influential, or establised, but only the context can help choose the exact meaning.

Comment: Please, provide some additional information. Гадания на гуще - дело неблагодарное.

Comment: Read about "Вор в законе" --- [Thief in law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thief_in_law). This is a well-known expression. There is no other well-known expression of this kind. In particular, there is nothing like the English "mother-in-law".

Comment: nope, it's just a (quite stupid, as to me) word joke.
PS - it is always better to provide some context.

Answer (score 6):

If this is analogy with "вор в законе", then it means respected, authoritative.

Comment: Yes, "вор в законе" is called by journalists as "криминальный авторитет". So, "математик в законе" will be "математический авторитет".

Answer (score 5):

First of all, that is almost certainly a joke. It means something like "a villainous mathematician" or "a mathematician gang boss". It depends on context, but usually something like that is a good-natured joke and doesn't mean disrespect.